# iterate through array and print html foreach key/value Javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iteration

Okay, so this function is doing everything i expect until i hit the print to html section. For whatever reason, it will only print out one index at time rather than printing each index in the array.

The offending portion of this code located @ lines 19-23 in the included snippet.

```
$.each(_services, function(index,value)
{
    $('#test').html('<p>' +index+ ":" +value+ '</p>');
});
```

```js
// services object -- initially EMPTY
var _services = {};

$('#serviceList input[type=checkbox]').change( function serviceList()
{
 // For each checkbox inside the #serviceList container, do the following
 $(this).each( function()
 {
  // Set "_key" to id of checkbox
  var _key = (this).id;

  // If checkbox is checked -- ADD -- its key/value pair to the "services" object
  // else checkbox is unchecked -- DELETE -- key/value pair from "services" object
  (this.checked) ? _services[ _key ] = (this).value : delete _services[ _key ];

  // console.log(_services);
 }); // END foreach()

 // foreach services print paragraph to display key/value
 $.each(_services, function(index,value)
 {
  $('#test').html('<p>' +index+ ":" +value+ '</p>');
    }); // END services foreach
  
}); // END serviceList()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
</head
  
<body>

<ul id="serviceList"> <!-- changed to list in the tutorial -->
  <li><input id="id_a" type="checkbox" value="40"> Test A</li>
  <li><input id="id_b" type="checkbox" value="50"> Test B</li>
  <li><input id="id_c" type="checkbox" value="60"> Test C</li>
  <li><input id="id_d" type="checkbox" value="70"> Test D</li>
</ul>

<div id="test" style="height: 500px; width: 700px; background-color: pink;"></div>

    
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are clearing container's `innerHTML` every time you write new line. Instead you should [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) content and clear container before `each` loop:

```
$('#test').empty(); 
$.each(_services, function(index,value) {
    $('#test').append('<p>' +index+ ":" +value+ '</p>');
});
```

Check the demo below:

```js
var _services = {};

$('#serviceList input[type=checkbox]').change(function serviceList() {
    // For each checkbox inside the #serviceList container, do the following
    $(this).each(function () {
        // If checkbox is checked -- ADD -- its key/value pair to the "services" object
        // else checkbox is unchecked -- DELETE -- key/value pair from "services" object
        this.checked ? _services[this.id] = this.value : delete _services[this.id];

        // console.log(_services);
    }); // END foreach()

    // foreach services print paragraph to display key/value
    $('#test').empty();
    $.each(_services, function (index, value) {
        $('#test').append('<p>' + index + ":" + value + '</p>');
    });

}); // END serviceList()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="serviceList"> <!-- changed to list in the tutorial -->
  <li><input id="id_a" type="checkbox" value="40"> Test A</li>
  <li><input id="id_b" type="checkbox" value="50"> Test B</li>
  <li><input id="id_c" type="checkbox" value="60"> Test C</li>
  <li><input id="id_d" type="checkbox" value="70"> Test D</li>
</ul>

<div id="test" style="height: 150px; background-color: pink;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, the .empty() before the loop never occurred to me. Much appreciated.

Comment: Yea, you can also use `.html('')` for the same purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If understand your problem correctly, this is because you are overwriting the contents of the `#test` element each time. How about appending:

```
   $('#test').append('<p>' +index+ ":" +value+ '</p>');
```

Comment: I tried append before posting, unfortunately it cause each iteration to repeat the last. i end up with 10 p tags if all checkbox are checked

Comment: @kash101 can you use alert to see the values of `index` and `value`, like this `alert(index+ ":" +value);`

Comment: yea the alerts were running them one off at a time as well. The .append with a clearing before the loop took care of the issue. I swear its the subtle things that sneak up and bite you on the ass most times